# How to highlight navbar based on the page I am in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Im trying to highlight the navbar based on the page im in, for example:

[Page I am currently in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk5TU.png)

to

[The next page I am in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li4BJ.png)

As you can see the page I move to is highlighted. How can I do this in code?

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar_welcome">
  <a href="index.php?action=home" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbspHome</a>
  <a href="index.php?action=home"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>&nbspHistory</a>
  <a href="index.php?action=setting"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbspProfile</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you moving page by actually navigating to a new page, or simple dynamically updating the page?

Comment: @Light Moving to a new page and at the same time have the navbar highlighted like so

Comment: @user11453590 That didn't answer his question

Comment: @Light Yes I am navigating to a new page

Comment: @user11453590 No you're not, they're all index.php.. lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your $_GET variables to echo an inline `background-style` attribute on page generation.

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar_welcome">
  <a href="index.php?action=home" class="active">
     <i class="fas fa-home" <?php if ($_GET['action']=='home') { echo 'style="background-color: grey;"'; }?>></i>&nbspHome
  </a>
  <a href="index.php?action=hsitory">
     <i class="fas fa-chart-line" <?php if ($_GET['action']=='history') { echo 'style="background-color: grey;"'; }?>></i>&nbspHistory
  </a>
  <a href="index.php?action=setting">
     <i class="fas fa-user" <?php if ($_GET['action']=='setting') { echo 'style="background-color: grey;"'; }?>></i>&nbspProfile
  </a>
</div>
```

You could also do something similar in `<style>` tags in the header, either works.

Comment: @user11453590 It would be helpful if you actually told me what the error was

Comment: it says unexpected '='

Comment: Code works, however when I click on the Profile the background doesnt move to it. Its kinda hard to explain but Im glad u wanna help, would it be fine for u if we move this to a chat?

Comment: Can't do that on current network, make sure that the GET values I have attributed are actually being sent.

Comment: @user11453590 would you mind marking this as answered if it satisfies the original question?

Answer (score -1):

It is very Simple HTML class handling. If you don't have certain php or ajax criteria.
For each page add class `active` to the Nav tags.

**For example:**

In **Page1** add `class='active'` to the current Nav tag *(home.php)*

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar_welcome">
  <a href="Home.php" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbspHome</a>
  <a href="History.php"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>&nbspHistory</a>
  <a href="Profile.php"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbspProfile</a>
</div>
```

In **Page2** add `class='active'` to the current Nav tag *(History.php)*

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar_welcome">
  <a href="Home.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbspHome</a>
  <a href="History.php" class="active"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>&nbspHistory</a>
  <a href="Profile.php"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbspProfile</a>
</div>
```

Add class `active` in CSS like so

```
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Continue to do that for all the pages that have the same Nav bar. It should do it.

Reference: https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/navigation/

Comment: These are all on the same page, I take it he didn't know hot to explain that. It's dynamically generated with PHP as the links all redirect to index.php with a different $_GET variable. They thus, if he is writing it correctly, have the same header element and cannot be changed this way.

Comment: Got it. Than your answer makes more sense.